# (Xcode, Spritekit) Is there a way to add sprites at design time with script?

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm make a puzzle app with Xcode/Spritekit.

There are lots of puzzle pieces, during design time, I would have to manually create, place in scene, and more importantly name them and name the puzzle texture they use. Most of this could be automated with some kind of scripting I assume. Because my hand will fall off from all that typing.....

I need to do this in design window in Xcode, not at runtime.

1) create sprite

2) name sprite, something like PuzzlePiece_001, PuzzlePiece_002...PuzzlePiece_NNN

3) assign puzzle piece the texture PuzzlePieceTex_001, PuzzlePieceTex_002, PuzzlePieceTex_NNN

This would save a whole lot of time if I can use a script

Comment: Why do you need to do it via the scene editor, rather than in your code? If you can explain that, we might be able to help.

Comment: At design time, I have to add all the puzzle pieces. So, say I have a puzzle of a castle. That is made up of 50 puzzle pieces. I have to add a sprite into scene in xcode at design time, then name it CastlePuzzlePiece_001 for first puzzle piece, then assign this puzzle piece the image CastlePuzzlePiece_001.png, then do this for puzzle piece #2, and #3 etc up to puzzle piece #50. Which is very tedious to do manually. Is there a way I could automate this with a script?

Comment: do you really mean "at design time"? that would imply that you want a script to add them to the scene editor for you to design a level...or do you just mean procedurally generate these pieces per level when the level loads for the end user?

Comment: I open up XCode, and open up the SKS file. I need to add the puzzle sprites into the SKS file, into the SKS file's design view in XCode. I drag sprite into scene, name sprite, assign it the png file. There are a lot of puzzle pieces, so doing this manually is tedious. Is there a way to automate this process with a script?

Comment: What I want is a script that I can run, in XCode like:    for (x=1;x<=numberOfPuzzlePieces; x++) {create sprite, name it "CastlePuzzlePiece"+x, assign it "CastlePuzzlePiece"+x+".png"}

Comment: Automate with code IN YOUR PROGRAM. Xcode is not scriptable; if you have the idea of a script to add the elements programatically to your scene, why does this have to be done in the scene editor and not in your program? The scene editor is for manually placing those elements that can;t easily be added in code.

Comment: The reason is, that after they are added, the reference puzzle image has to be done manually, otherwise, yes, this could have been done in swift code at runtime.

Comment: Just like with real puzzle, you need a reference image of the completed puzzle to work off of. In puzzle app, I can't just use a single image, I have to create the completed reference image with puzzle pieces, the reason is because the puzzle piece that the user drags around is tested against the set puzzle piece in the reference "image", if the puzzle piece matches the coordinates of the set puzzle piece, then it is considered a match.

Comment: ![screen capture](https://preview.ibb.co/e21soy/example.png).

Comment: ![example](https://preview.ibb.co/hiQkQd/Screen_Shot_2018_05_10_at_11_06_01_AM.png).

Comment: The completed puzzle image, in my example in previous post, is the reference image for the puzzle user (he can turn the reference image display on or off). It is also made up of puzzle pieces. Like I said, the reason is for testing intersection when user places the puzzle piece down, if they are close enough (that is it's in the correct spot), then it is considered to be correctly placed, This is why I can't just use a single image for a reference image. I would need to position pieces for reference image manually, as this can't be done at runtime since I do not have the coordinates for them

Comment: Components run during design time.  you should be able to pretty much build a majority of your game by using components

Comment: @SteveIves, to answer your question as to "why", it could potentially save a lot of loading time. Personally, the one thing I can tell you I hate about apps is needless loading times.  So many apps waste my time with loading (Large companies are the worst at this), so the one benefit an indie developer can do that beats those large manufactured apps is to keep loading time to a minimum.